# how to write a custom hadoop group mapping class

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

I have a use case where I would like to integrate hdfs with my application. User management is handeled by the application. Now on HDFS side to fetch groups of a user we can use any of the predined ways defined here.
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/GroupsMapping.html#Composite_Groups_Mapping

But in my case since my application handles users and groups is there a way to create a custom GroupMapping which talks to my application to get user and group details ?

Comment: If your application isn't using LDAP / Kerberos, you'll have to write a custom identity provider for Hadoop, which doesn't sound easy to me

Answer (score 0):

This component of Hadoop is entirely extensible. You simply need to write a custom implementation of the [GroupMappingServiceProvider](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/security/GroupMappingServiceProvider.html), which has just 3 methods - one to translate a user to a list of groups that user is in, and two for managing the caching of the mapping. All you need to do after implementing this interface is place a JAR with your custom implementation onto the classpath of your HDFS JVMs and then specify it in the `hadoop.security.group.mapping` configuration.